# Manage Common Dependencies with Parent Services in symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I noticed a strange thing with managing common dependencies with parent services in symfony 3.1.6.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html

I try to define a user_manager service which extends fos user manager service.

```
    // AppBundle/Service/UserManager.php

    namespace AppBundle\Service;

    use FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager as BaseUserManager;

    class UserManager extends BaseUserManager
    {
    }
```

```
    // AppBundle/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php

    namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
    use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

    class AppExtension extends Extension
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
        {
            $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
            $loader->load('services.yml');
        }
    }
```

```
    # AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

    services:
        app.user_manager:
            class: AppBundle\Service\UserManager
            parent: fos_user.user_manager.default
```

When trying to get service in contoller

```
    

        $this->get('app.user_manager');
```

Then the exception is thrown:
'You have requested a non-existent service "app.user_manager".'

However, if I define my custom service in a different way:

```
    # AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

    services:
        app.user_manager:
            class: AppBundle\Service\UserManager
            arguments:
                - '@fos_user.util.password_updater'
                - '@fos_user.util.canonical_fields_updater'
                - '@fos_user.object_manager'
                - '%fos_user.model.user.class%'
```

Then it works fine.
Moreover, it used to work like this with a "parent" before, in symfony 2.8

What could be wrong here and how it should be done properly with symfony 3.1?

p.s. I tried to clear cache, and also remove var/cache* directory, but that doesn't help

Comment: The error message really indicates the service file never got loaded.  Are you positive you had everything cleared when you tried it?  Might try again just to be sure.

Comment: Yes I'm positive.
I have also narrowed down a problem. I have created two services myself and tried to use "parent" and it actually works. So the problem is exactly in extending "fos_user.user_manager.default".

Comment: Hey @Phantom, did you managed to solve this? Or do you still need help?